# How to address / access dynamicly created Objects?

Tags: java, object

i try to address dynamicly created Objects to get values via methods.
I crated the Objects dynamicly and used a ArrayList which helds the objectnames.
My ArrayList is called arraylist and the values of the List are created by users-input (Scanner) The values are f.e.("Mike","Nick","John").

**My class "Player":**

```
public class Player {

    String playerName = "Player";
    int counter1 = 20;
    int counter2 = 50;

    public String get_playerName(){
        return playerName;
    }    
    public int get_counter1(){
        return counter1;
    }    
    public int get_counter2(){
        return counter2;
    }    


    public Player(String Name){
    playerName = Name;
    }

}
```

Here's where i created the Objects dynamicly:

```
int playersCount = arraylist.size(); //Size of ArrayList with Players names

//create Players dynamicly
for(int i = 0; i < playersCount; i++){
     Player playerName = new Player(arraylist.get(i));
}
```

How can i get a specific Player-Value from Player-Class (fe: let's say, John is on the move, haw to get his counter1 via get_counter1())
How to address a specific Player-Object ?

Thanks alot in advance to everybody answering!

Michael

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697356/creating-array-of-new-object-with-no-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the players in a Map which maps the player names to the player objects.

```
    HashMap<String, Player> mp = new HashMap<String, Player>();
    for(int i = 0; i < playersCount; i++){
           Player player = new Player(arraylist.get(i));
           mp.put(arraylist.get(i), player);
    }


    // ... 

    Player p = mp.get("John");

    // now use the player John i.e. the p object
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a `HashMap<String,Player>` to store the references to the `Players` you create.

```
    int playersCount = arraylist.size(); //Size of ArrayList with Players names
    Map<String,Player> players = new HashMap<>();

    //create Players dynamicly
    for(int i = 0; i < playersCount; i++){
        Player player = new Player(arraylist.get(i));
        players.put (arraylist.get(i), player);
    }
```

The `players` variable should be a member of the class that creates the players, not a local variable.

Then you can retrieve a player with :

```
    Player player = players.get("John");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a `List<Player>` and you are using java 8, then you can use the stream API to find by name (or any other property). This will be slower than using a `Map`, but you can search/map/etc your collections in a more flexible way.

```
Optional<Player> optPlayer = arraylist
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> "John".equals(p.get_playerName()))
    .findFirst();

if(optPlayer.isPresent()) {
    //player found
    Player p = optPlayer.get();
}
```